# Авторизация в VK с сохранением параметров?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, javafx

Подскажите, возможно ли во время авторизации приложения в вк через `WebView`, получить данные авторизации (логин/пароль) и использовать их впоследствии для получения токена просто отправляя url c запросом?

Так же интересует, каким образом проверять валидность токена при последующих загрузках приложения? Как я понимаю, получая значение `expires_in` можно прикинуть дату окончания действия токена, и исходя продолжать пользоваться текущим или получать новый?

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно сделать черед `javascript`.

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
Engine engine = webView.getEngine();
engive.executeScript("alert(\'alert\')");
```

Вместо алерта необходимо реализовать свою логику ( например, при изменении поля получать содержимое этого поля).

Но это не есть хорошо - хранить пользовательские логин и пароль ( см [пункт 2](https://vk.com/dev/rules)).

Полученный токен можно хранить в файле, и постоянно его оттуда дергать ( или в любом другом месте, главное, чтобы не в самом приложении, потому как при выходе из приложения токен потеряется)

Если токен будет не валиден, то на любой ваш запрос придет ответ с ошибкой. Вы можете постоянно проверять респонз - если там есть данная ошибка, то необходимо получить новый токен ( читай - перелогониться).

Comment: Да в том и дело, что "перелогиниваться" для получения нового токена не хочется. Да и на практике, практически во всех приложениях такого рода учетные данные вводятся один раз (а в следующий только при смене пароля). Данный кейс - самый удобный, как мне кажется. Плюс, наверное можно класс с данными авторизации сериализовать в байт код, как минимум, чтобы сложнее было напрямую прочитать.

Comment: Он несомненно удобен, но будете ли пользоваться приложением, зная, что он хранит ваши личные данные? Из учета, что это неофициальное приложение? А то что можно сериализовать, можно так же и десериализовать.